# Cómo colocar color a las letras escritas por un oninput

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Necesito que a la hora de escribir en un input este se vea reflejado en oninput y que lo escrito cada letra tenga un color diferente

```
function miFuction(){

    var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML= x;

}

(function(){
    InputEvent.oninput(function(){  
        
        var coloruno=document.getElementById('color-uno');
        var colordos= documet.getElementById('color-dos');
        var colortres=document.getElementById('color-tres');
        var colorcuatro=document.getElementById('color-cuatro');
        var colorquinto=document.getElementById('color-cinco');
        var colorseis=document.getElementById('color-sexta');
        var letrasuno=["a","b","c","d"];
        var letrasdos=["e","f","g","h"];
        var letrastres=["i","j","k","l"];
        var letrascuatro=["m","n","ñ","o"];
        var letrascinco=["p","q","r","s","t"];
        var letrasexta=["u","v","w","x","y","z"];

        coloruno.style.color=letrasuno[Math.floor(Math.random() * letrasuno.length)];
        colordos.style.color=letrasdos[Math.floor(Math.random() * letrasdos.length)];
        colortres.style.color=letrastres[Math.floor(Math.random() * letrastres.length)];
        colorcuatro.style.color=letrascuatro[Math.floor(Math.random() * letrascuatro.length)];
        colorquinto.style.color=letrascinco[Math.floor(Math.random() * letrascinco.length)];
        colorseis.style.color= letrasexta[Math.floor(Math.random() *  letrasexta.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero sería definir que es "color diferente", porque a la vista 2 colores pueden ser iguales, pero tienen código son distintos.

Un color puede escribirse desde 3 colores distintos R,G,B (Rojo, verde, azul), cuyas "tonalidades" (no sé si ese será el nombre técnico) van desde 0 a 255, en hexadecimal de 0 a FF

Entonces si combinas los 3, el color mínimo que tienes es 000000, y el máximo es FFFFFF que es igual a 16.777.215, es decir puedes tener casi 17 millones de colores distintos

Es decir, si empiezas con un contador desde 0 hasta 16.777.215, te dará un color distinto, luego puedes transformar ese número a hexadecimal usando la siguiente función

```
index.toString(16).padStart(6, "0")
```

Donde toString(16) convierte a hexadecimal un número y padStart agrega ceros a la izquierda (en este caso un máximo de 6) para mantener el formato RGB

El código sería el siguiente:

```js
const Salida =  document.getElementById("Salida");
let index=0;

function colocarletra(){
   let span = document.createElement("span");
   span.style.color = "#" + index.toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
   span.innerText = event.key;
   index++;
   Salida.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
#Salida{
word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Entrada" onkeypress="colocarletra()" />
<div id="Salida"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: pero como le asigano a cada letra un color diferente es decir que si escribo pedro   la p----color verde// e----color rojo//   d-----el color amarillo// r----azul// o----- rosado

Comment: @LauraYeraldinAcevedoHernand Es lo que te intentaba explicar, no existen ni 3 ni 14 ni mil colores, son 17 millones. Empezando por el #000000, #000001, #000002.... La diferencias de estos 3 primeros es mínima y al ojo humano es indetectable, pero en rigor son colores diferentes.

Comment: @LauraYeraldinAcevedoHernand Por otro lado, quizás yo entendí mal el trabajo, si me lo explicas de otra manera puedo cambiar el código